# How to launch let'schat (nodejs app) as deamon?

Tags: node.js, systemd, daemon, npm

I have installed "let's chat" on my server. In the documentation, they say to launch the application with

```
npm start
```

from the directory where the application is installed.

But i'm unable to launch it with systemd. I want the application to be always online. So it works if I manually launch

```
cd /MIDDLE/uow/lets-chat/ && /bin/npm start
```

but not if I configure the line in Execstart from systemd. I try with the same line, I try with npm, I try with "node ./apps.js"  :

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/cd /MIDDLE/uow/lets-chat/ && /usr/local/bin/node /MIDDLE/uow/lets-chat/app.js
```

(I try with or without absolute path for my command but it change nothing).

I don't know how to launch this application as deamon in my centos. How can I do please ?

Thank you,

A.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/792430/126632

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set both `ExecStart=` and `WorkingDirectory=` to the appropriate values. For example:

```
WorkingDirectory=/MIDDLE/uow/lets-chat
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/node /MIDDLE/uow/lets-chat/app.js
```